# PDF file content has been lose when send via API using APEX_WEB_SERVICE

Tags: oracle, rest, plsql

I want to send multiple PDF file and text data via REST API. I'm using APEX_WEB_SERVICE. Before make a request I have to covert list of PDF file from server to BLOB through "for" loop and using BFILENAME syntax and store them using APEX_WEB_SERVICE.APPEND_TO_MULTIPART. Everything is good but the content of PDF files has been lost.
This is my code:

```
v_bfile := bfilename(v_dir_name, fs.file_name_ser);
dbms_lob.createtemporary(v_blob, true);
dbms_lob.open(v_bfile, dbms_lob.file_readonly);
dbms_lob.open(v_blob, dbms_lob.lob_readwrite);
dbms_lob.loadfromfile(v_blob,
                      v_bfile,
                      dbms_lob.getlength(v_bfile));
dbms_lob.close(v_bfile);
dbms_lob.close(v_blob);
apex_web_service.append_to_multipart(p_multipart    => apex_parts,
                                     p_name         => 'files',
                                     p_filename     => nvl(fs.file_name,
                                                                       fs.file_name_ser),
                                     p_content_type => 'application/pdf',
                                     p_body_blob    => v_blob);
dbms_lob.freetemporary(v_blob);
```

```
apex_web_service.g_request_headers.delete();
apex_web_service.set_request_headers(p_name_01        => 'Authorization',
                                     p_value_01       => 'Bearer ' ||
                                                                 p_token,
                                     p_name_02        => 'Content-Type',
                                     p_value_02       => 'multipart/form-data',
                                     p_name_03        => 'Transfer-Encoding',
                                     p_value_03       => 'chunked',
                                     p_reset          => true,
                                     p_skip_if_exists => true);
l_resp_body := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(p_url         => l_url,
                                                  p_http_method => 'POST',
                                                  p_body_blob   => apex_web_service.generate_request_body(apex_parts),
                                                  p_wallet_path => l_wallet_path,
                                                  p_wallet_pwd  => l_wallet_pw);
```

I don't know why this happen. Hope someone has an experience with this trouble can help me.